# WINFORM C++ Managed string->unmanaged string produces unexpected results when combined with fstream

Tags: c++, winforms, string, clr, managed

Right. So I'm trying to do this:

```
    String^ ai = textBox4->Text;
char* towrite = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(ai ).ToPointer();
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(towrite));
string write = string(towrite);

ofstream filea;
filea.open("Logtoreadfrom.txt");
filea<< write; 
filea.close();
```

Where I'm trying to copy the text from textBox4 to a file I create.

I make the managed string "ai" the text from the text box,
I convert it to the char towrite by marshalling from the StringToHGlobalAnsi command,
I then define the unmanaged string write as the char towrite

I define filea,
I create filea,
I write to file a,
I close file a.

When I open filea, My result typically consists of the random letters that have nothing to do with the text I input.

I assume I'm doing something wrong, so could anyone point out where?

Answer (score 1):

You free the memory containing the unmanaged string, then try to use it. Try this:

```
String^ ai = textBox4->Text;
char* towrite = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(ai ).ToPointer();
string write = string(towrite);
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(towrite));

ofstream filea;
filea.open("Logtoreadfrom.txt");
filea<< write; 
filea.close();
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that. Thanks, should have realized.